# xmllint, bash and mixing single and double qoutes

Tags: bash, xpath, xmllint

I have a bash script very much like this:

```
# xpath query text
XPATH_FORM_ID="//form[@method='post']//input[@name='form_build_id']/@id" 
# surround with double quotes
XPATH_FORM_ID='"'"${XPATH_FORM_ID}"'"' 
DUMMY="$(xmllint --recover --html index.html --xpath ${XPATH_FORM_ID} 2> /dev/null)"
echo "Dummy: ${DUMMY}"
echo "xmllint --recover --html index.html --xpath ${XPATH_FORM_ID} 2> /dev/null"
```

It will echo this:

```
Dummy: //form[@method='post']//input[@name='form_build_id']/@id
xmllint --recover --html index.html --xpath "//form[@method='post']//input[@name='form_build_id']/@id" 2> /dev/null
```

I was expecting the output of the echoed `xmllint` command:

```
$ xmllint --recover --html index.html --xpath "//form[@method='post']//input[@name='form_build_id']/@id" 2> /dev/null
 id="form-e9f5fe8e157329734722a31aed3f05fe" id="form-5de9fec879730335baa4860948245e27" id="form-83290b55eae399217486ec68e08be3d1" id="form-c1e275e97051aff023ca0526e17c37bb" id="form-13af4fe1b67e0b94462fa7d763b9bffe"
```

How can I make sure the `$()` expansion returns what I expect?

A few of the motivations why I have set it up like this:

- `--recover --html` because most web-sites promising `xhtml` actually produce conformant output
- `2> /dev/null` to ditch `stderr` so that the `--recover` information is not ending on the screen
- single quotes in the XPATH as the attribute comparisons to string literals seem to require that
- double quotes around the XPATH as to allow for more complex xpath expressions**

** In the future, I want to zoom in on the `id` of the form having an input with one particular `name` (the html is riddled with forms, this is the way the site keeps them apart). When I have the id, I want to use `string()` to get the text portion of the `id`. Without double quotes, this won't work on the command-line, so I presume it is needed inside a bash script as well.

Comment: Don't stick quotes inside the variable. Use them on the variable expansion. Also drop `2 > /dev/null` until you are done testing to see any relevant errors from `xmllint` about your XPATH. Also use `set -x` to see what the shell is *actually* running.

Comment: Using `echo "$commandstr"` to print a shell command is never safe practice. `printf '%q ' "${command_args[@]}"; echo` with an array.

Comment: See BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm relatively a noob on bash, so can you elaborate on the `printf` construct, as it is different from what is used in your link.

Comment: If you're using `set -x`, you don't need the `printf` construct.

Comment: that said, `printf '%q ' "an argument" "another argument"` emits a string which will, when copied-and-pasted back to the shell, be parsed as itself -- even if those arguments contain nonprintable characters, whitespace, or fall into other corner cases. `echo` isn't useful here: You can't distinguish between `echo one two three` and `echo "one two" three`; `printf '%q '`, by contrast, makes that distinction clear.

Comment: BTW, using all-caps names for your own shell variables (as opposed to builtins and system variables) is bad form. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You're failing to distinguish between syntactic quotes (meaningful to the shell) and literal quotes in your data. Adding **literal** double quotes does absolutely no good in terms of changing how the shell treats the relevant string: They stay data and never become syntax without invoking `eval`, which you very much don't want to do.

A correct way to run this query in a reusable manner might look like the following:

```
xpath_form_id="//form[@method='post']//input[@name='form_build_id']/@id"
query() {
  xmllint --recover --html index.html --xpath "$xpath_form_id" "$@" 2>/dev/null
}
```

Thereafter:

```
content=$(query in.xml)
```

...or...

```
content=$(query <in.xml)
```

Note that the outer double quotes when running `"$xpath_form_id"` are semantic, not literal. They are not passed to xmllint, but are instead treated as an instruction for the shell not to string-split or glob-expand the contents of `xpath_form_id` when expanding this variable.

---

By contrast, when you run

```
xpath_form_id_q='"'"$xpath_form_id"'"'
```

...you put *literal* quotes on the string; they aren't honored by the shell as directives on how to parse a string on expansion, but are instead passed to the underlying tool being invoked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will redesign my bash script. Then probably have more questions which I will post as new ones.